# Laravel Dusk - NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, testing, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to test my login form with dusk. On the frontend I use vue component. When I try to access the email input and to set value, I receive the error:

```
1) Tests\Browser\LoginTest::testExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body [dusk="login-email"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.105)
```

**Login form:**

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm" class="q-mt-lg">
        <div class="col q-mb-md">
          <q-input
            v-model="formData.email"
            outlined
            type="email"
            dusk="login-email"
            class="col"
            data-email
            label="Email"
            ref="email"
            stack-label
            :rules="[ val => validateEmail(val) || 'Please enter a valid email address']"
            lazy-rules />
        </div>
        <div class="col q-mb-md">
          <q-input
            v-model="formData.password"
            type="password"
            dusk="login-password"
            outlined
            class="col"
            label="Password"
            ref="password"
            stack-label
            :rules="[ val => val.length >= 8 || 'Password must be at least 8 characters']"
            lazy-rules />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <q-btn
            type="submit"
            dusk="login-btn"
            name="login"
            class="login"
            color="primary"
            label="Login" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

**My test:**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use App\User;

class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function ($browser) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('@login-email', 'test@test.com')
                    ->type('@login-password', '12345678')
                    ->press('@login-btn')
                    ->assertPathIs('/');
        });
    }
}
```

My project works on http://localhost:3002

In .env file - APP_URL=http://localhost

**In DuskTestCase.php**

```
protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
            '--no-sandbox'
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
```

If I change the APP_URL to http://localhost:3002 the error is the same. Can you help me with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with Dusk.  And many, many more.

There are a few things that you can do to fix this error, but it can be challenging to find the appropriate fix for your particular build.

- Update Chrome to the latest version
- Update the Chrome WebDriver
- One that got me multiple times: ensure the `APP_URL` variable in your **.env** file. Make sure this is the correct URL that the live application is running.  IE the parameter must match reality.
- Try without passing the css selector into the type method.  According to the [Dusk Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/dusk#using-forms), you don't have to do this - Dusk will attempt to find the field with the given name attribute.  The css may be causing more issues than its worth

So for example:

```
$browser->visit('/login')
    ->type('login-email', 'test@test.com')
    ->type('login-password', '12345678')
    ->press('login-btn')
    ->assertPathIs('/');
```

Comment: How is your example any different from passing a CSS selector?

Comment: A CSS selector is... well... CSS.  The difference is that Dusk has trouble finding CSS selectors at some points - and hit or miss - can sometimes find by name, or the 'dusk' attribute.  Logically it should *not* be different, but over and over again, Dusk seems to treat them differently and YMMV depending on that difference.  My example is not different than a CSS selector, my bullet point was speaking to using the name as a thing to attempt.